# Summernote: Manually open link dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I've trying to write a script that automatically displays the summernote link dialog box when I click a button.

For instance, I have the following button:

`<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info use_hyperlink" data-href="//files.examples.org.uk/song.mp3" type="button">Copy</button>`

So in my js I've got:

```
$("#linklist").on("click", "button.use_hyperlink", function () {
    var href = $(this).data("href")
    modal = $("div.note-editor.note-frame.panel.panel-default div.modal.link-dialog")
    modal.addClass("in").modal("show")
    modal.find("input.note-link-url.form-control.note-form-control.note-input").val(href)
    modal.find("button.note-btn.note-btn-primary.note-link-btn").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disabled").attr("type","button")
})
```

Which opens the dialog, successfully pastes the `href` but clicking the `Insert Link` button submits the form that the summernote resides in.

Looking at the [summernote code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.js) on line `6765` there is a function called `showLinkDialog` which I imagine is the one I want.  However when I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("textarea#summernote").summernote({height: 500});
    $("#linklist").on("click", "button.use_hyperlink", function () {
        var href = $(this).data("href")
        $("textarea#summernote").showLinkDialog({
            url: href
        });
    })  
})
```

I get an `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).showLinkDialog is not a function`.

Answer (score 2):

Try trigger clicking the button

```
$('.note-insert [aria-label^="Link"').trigger('click')
```